# Error installing any gem packages ::: gem install rails or gem install dashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, suse

Receiving below error while installing any package and I using

```
gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib64/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out


 # gem -v
2.1.5
 # ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]
```

Can anyone Please help in fixing this problem, as I have already tried changing the export PATH=$PATH:/ ruby path and also tried to install ruby-dev but couldn't find it on rubygems.com or through gems install ruby-dev or ruby-devel.

Comment: What platform are you on?  I'm guessing some flavor of Linux?  Have you tried using [rvm](https://rvm.io)?  Ruby 1.8.7 is pretty ancient, and RubyGems 2.1.5 is pretty new, how'd you end up with that combination?

Comment: Suse linux is on SLES11SP2, so we had ruby 1.8.7 and since I installed rubygem it was on 2.1.5

Comment: Use some Ruby version manager like [RVM](http://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/) (my personal choice). If you don't want to use any of these (which is bad idea) then you need to install some kind of `dev` version of Ruby that will provide headers needed for native Ruby extensions.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem:

```
gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing atomic:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
```

System info:

```
  [root@server ~]# uname -a
    Linux server.com 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 28 17:19:38 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    [root@server ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
    CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
    [root@server ~]# ruby -v
    ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

After running commands:

```
yum install ruby-rdoc ruby-devel -y
gem update
gem update --system
```

I see:

```
[root@server ~]# gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed atomic-1.1.14
Fetching: thread_safe-0.1.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.1.3
Fetching: activesupport-4.0.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

And i think that CentOS 6.4 at default repos does not support rails.
To solve problem, we need to install ruby from sources:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
rvm requirements
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
rvm rubygems current
```

We don't need to remove default ruby-1.8.x 
Just exec source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh after rvm installed
Thanks to rvm!!!

Remember! To install rails from RVM, you need after installation ruby-1.9.3 run this command:

```
gem update --system 1.8.25
```

We did this to avoid error:

```
/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `add_frozen_gem_path': undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:60:in `load_initializer'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:44:in `run'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:17:in `boot!'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:123
    from script/server:2:in `require'
    from script/server:2
```